# Incompatible types - is it because an array is already a pointer?

Tags: c++

In the below code I create an object based off of the books structure, and to have it hold multiple "books" I set is an array (the object that is defined/initiated, that is). However, whenever I went to test my knowledge of pointers (the practice helps) and attempted to make a pointer that points to the created object, it gives me the error:

*C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\Project\wassuip\main.cpp|18|error: incompatible types in assignment of 'books*' to 'books* [4]'|*

May I ask, is this because the object book_arr[] is already considered a pointer as it's an array? Thanks (new to C++ and just want to verify).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

#define NUM 4

using namespace std;

struct books {
    float price;
    string name;
    int rating;
} book_arr[NUM];

int main()
{
    books *ptr[NUM];
    ptr = &book_arr[NUM];

    string str;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
        cout << "Enter book name: " << endl;
        cin >> ptr[i]->name;
        cout << "Enter book price: " << endl;
        cin >> str;
        stringstream(str) << ptr[i]->price;
        cout << "Enter book rating: " << endl;
        cin >> str;
        stringstream(str) << ptr[i]->rating;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**NEW CODE AFTER ANSWERS (NO ERRORS) **

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

#define NUM 4

using namespace std;

/* structures */
struct books {
    float price;
    string name;
    int rating;
} book[NUM];

/* prototypes */
void printbooks(books book[NUM]);

int main()
{
    string str;

    books *ptr = book;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
        cout << "Enter book name: " << endl;
        cin >> ptr[i].name;
        cout << "Enter book price: " << endl;
        cin >> str;
        stringstream(str) << ptr[i].price;
        cout << "Enter book rating: " << endl;
        cin >> str;
        stringstream(str) << ptr[i].rating;
    }

    return 0;
}

void printbooks(books book[NUM]){
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
        cout << "Title: \t" << book[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Price: \t$" << book[i].price << endl;
        cout << "Racing: \t" << book[i].rating << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see you are including `<vector>`. Why don’t you use `std::vector` instead of those inferior C-arrays?

Comment: @WTP'-- Would that mean any substantial advantage?...

Comment: Yes, such as decent semantics and clear syntax, and you’re actually writing C++ rather than C. See [this article by DeadMG](http://codepuppy.co.uk/cpptuts/CClass/CArrays.aspx) on why C-arrays are terrible.

Comment: @WTP'--But this IS C++. I'm not trying to write C code. o.O

Comment: I know, so you should use `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: @WTP'-- Alright, thank you. I will do. :)

Comment: For starters, vectors don't decay to iterators; isn't that enough of an advantage? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[image: An array is not a pointer]

See [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/) for details.

Comment: *How do I use arrays in C++?* Not at all, use `std::vector`. :)

Answer (score -5):

That's right. For any array:

```
BlahClass myArray[COUNT];
```

`&myArray[0]` is equivalent to just `myArray`. i.e. The identifier `myArray` is a pointer to the first element of the array. This is why you'll hear it said, rather confusingly, that "arrays and pointers are the same thing in C++". What is really meant is that the array identifier is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: While it's true that you will here it said that *"arrays and pointers are the same thing in C++"*, the people who say it are completely wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Agreed. Updated my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Actually "the array identifier is a pointer to the first element of the array" is also incorrect. "The array identifier _decays_ to a pointer to the first element of the array" is correct.

Comment: Still not right.  What is really meant is *"an array can be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element"*

Comment: An array identifier **is not** a pointer to the first element. It may convert to one in certain situations, but that does not make it the same thing.

Comment: Here's a little code snippet I made a few days ago that demonstrates some of the differences between pointers and arrays. http://ideone.com/vb6Nj

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes unless people aren't reading my whole response. At no point in the answer do I state that arrays and pointers are the same thing. I explicitly refer to the array *identifier*, not the array itself. The idea in my answer was to guide  a beginner, starting with what they knew about pointers (addressing the actual question they had) through to an understanding of how array *identifiers* decay to a pointer to the *first element* of the array. 

But don't let that get in the way of a good sanctimonious trashing, including telling the OP to "Just Use STL (TM)".